# Two external 2k monitors to 2016 macbook

Tags: macos, mac

I have a macbook from 2016 (right before the touch bar came in).
As you know, it only has one usb-c port for use. So I have an adapter that extends one usb-c to one hdmi, three usb-3.0 type, ethernet port, and usb-c port.
Anyways, back to my origianl question, in such a setting, is it possible to run two 2k monitors?
Do I just need hdmi to usb adapter or is it not gonna work? Do I need some special adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do so by using some expensive module that enables multiple external monitors...  That was the only solution I found online for Macbook.